# sendgrid python api unsubscribe and manage list tags

Tags: python, email, sendgrid, jinja2

I'm using the sendgrid python api (i.e. I upload html using the set_html method, and i'm trying to customize the style of the default text for the following:

```
"Unsubscribe From This List | Manage Email Preferences"
```

I've tried using their 'Tracking' settings setting a custom replacement tag, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried many iterations like

```
<a href="[unsubscribe]">Click here to unsubscribe</a>
```

But nothing seems to work.

Here's what I have in the web app settings

[image: the sendgrid webapp settings for subscription tracking]

What text to I need to put in the html template? I read [this](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181498-Unsubscribe-via-Subscription-Tracking), and I'm doing it exactly like it says, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I used following in the replacement tag:

[image]

and then used it as `<a href='unsubscribe_tag_unique'>Unsubscribe</a>`.

> Note: if it doesn't work, wait for 5-10 minutes to sink. I think there is some syncing lag in sendgrid servers.